# Converting Django project from MySQL to Mongo, any major pitfalls?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I want to try Mongodb w/ mongoengine.  I'm new to Django and databases and I'm having a fit with Foreign Keys, Joins, Circular Imports (you name it).  I know I could eventually work through these issues but Mongo just seems like a simpler solution for what I am doing.  My question is I'm using a lot of pluggable apps (Imagekit, Haystack, Registration, etc) and wanted to know if these apps will continue to work if I make the switch. Are there any known headaches that I will encounter, if so I might just keep banging my head with MySQL.

Comment: If you're new to Django and databases, you might want to stick with the default ORM for a bit longer. It really is very powerful, and RDBMS's confuse most people at first, but they get MUCH easier as you go along. I'm confused about how you're having problems with FKs and Joins in Django though... the ORM means you don't have to deal directly with JOINs and FKs are pretty intuitive...

Comment: Which is all a roundabout way of saying that I don't think you're going to find Mongo significantly less complex for doing real tasks. It's a great engine, but NoSQL isn't a magic wand that makes things easy.

Comment: Well specifically, i'm trying to add another ForeignKey to one of my existing models and it will not import.  Did some reading and looks like I am the victim of "circular imports".  Still working on it now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't use one of the standard RDBMSs for all the standard Django apps, and then Mongo for your app. You'll just have to replace all the standard ways of processing things from the Django ORM with doing it the Mongo way.

So you can keep urls.py and its neat pattern matching, views will still get parameters, and templates can still take objects.

You'll lose querysets because I suspect they are too closely tied to the RDBMS models - but they are just lazily evaluated lists really. Just ignore the Django docs on writing models.py and code up your database business logic in a Mongo paradigm.

Oh, and you won't have the Django Admin interface for easy access to your data.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel), which is a young but promising attempt at a NoSQL backend for Django. Documentation is lacking at the moment, but it works great if you just work it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've used mongoengine with django but you need to create a file like mongo_models.py for example. In that file you define your Mongo documents. You then create forms to match each Mongo document. Each form has a save method which inserts or updates whats stored in Mongo. Django forms are designed to plug into any data back end ( with a bit of craft )

BEWARE: If you have very well defined and structured data that can be described in documents or models then don't use Mongo. Its not designed for that and something like PostGreSQL will work much better.

- I use PostGreSQL for relational or well structured data because its good for that. Small memory footprint and good response.
- I use Redis to cache or operate in memory queues/lists because its very good for that. great performance providing you have the memory to cope with it.
- I use Mongo to store large JSON documents and to perform Map and reduce on them ( if needed ) because its very good for that. Be sure to use indexing on certain columns if you can to speed up lookups.

Don't circle to fill a square hole. It won't fill it.

I've seen too many posts where someone wanted to swap a relational DB for Mongo because Mongo is a buzz word. Don't get me wrong, Mongo is really great... when you use it appropriately. I love using Mongo appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Upfront, it won't work for any existing Django app that ships it's models. There's no backend for storing Django's Model data in mongodb or other NoSQL storages *at the moment* and, database backends aside, models themselves are somewhat of a moot point, because once you get in to using someones app (`django.contrib` apps included) that ships model-template-view triads, whenever you require a slightly different model for your purposes you either have to edit the application code (plain wrong), dynamically edit the contents of imported Python modules at runtime (magical), fork the application source altogether (cumbersome) or provide additional settings (good, but it's a rare encounter, with `django.contrib.auth` probably being the only widely known example of an application that allows you to dynamically specify which model it will use, as is the case with user profile models through the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` setting).

This might sound bad, but what it really means is that you'll have to deploy SQL and NoSQL databases in parallel and go from an app-to-app basis--like Spacedman suggested--and if mongodb is the best fit for a certain app, hell, just roll your own custom app.

There's a lot of fine Djangonauts with NoSQL storages on their minds. If you followed the streams from the past Djangocon presentations, every year there's been important discussions about how Django should leverage NoSQL storages. I'm pretty sure, in this year or the next, someone will refactor the apps and models API to pave the path to a clean design that can finally unify all the different flavors of NoSQL storages as part of the Django core.

Comment: The refactoring work has already mostly been accomplished. 1.3 includes a bunch of changes that make NoSQL backends much easier to implement. There's a lot of stuff that still needs to be done, but it's definitely getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently tried this (although without Mongoengine).  There are a huge number of pitfalls, IMHO:

- No admin interface.
- No Auth  django.contrib.auth relies on the DB interface.
- Many things rely on django.contrib.auth.User.  For example, the RequestContext class.  This is a huge hindrance.
- No Registration (Relies on the DB interface and django.contrib.auth)

Basically, search through the django interface for references to django.contrib.auth and you'll see how many things will be broken.

That said, it's possible that MongoEngine provides some support to replace/augment django.contrib.auth with something better, but there are so many things that depend on it that it's hard to say how you'd monkey patch something that much.

Answer (score -1):

Primary pitfall (for me): no JOINs!